# Not able to display dialog contents when selection is enabled in primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I am trying to display dialog popup containing input text area on click of a command button in one of the column using the approach shown in showcase [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionByColumn.jsf) .In my case the datatable is a **multiple selection** enabled with the implementation of **datamodel**.The pop-up with text area only appears when the datatable has same feature as shown in the showcase but when multiple selection is implemented (with or without datamodel implementation)nothing gets displayed in the text area and i get the following exception when i check a row and click on the command button.When i directly click on command button no exception is thrown.

```
javax.faces.FacesException
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:86)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:508)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.gaic.datamodel.CarDataModel.getRowData(CarDataModel.java:27)
    at com.gaic.datamodel.CarDataModel.getRowData(CarDataModel.java:1)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getRowData(DataTable.java:953)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decodeMultipleSelection(SelectionFeature.java:71)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decode(SelectionFeature.java:40)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:57)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:796)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:228)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processDecodes(UIForm.java:216)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1048)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1048)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:926)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    ... 15 more
```

My JSF page snippet

```
<h:body>
<h:form id="form">

    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />

    <p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{tableBean.mediumCarsModel}"
    selection="#{tableBean.selectedCars}">

        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%" />

        <p:column headerText="Model" style="width:24%">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Year" style="width:24%">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Manufacturer" style="width:24%">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Color" style="width:24%">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="width:4%">
            <p:commandButton id="selectButton" update=":form:display"
                oncomplete="carDialog.show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="View">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{car}"
                    target="#{tableBean.selectedCar}" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>

    <p:dialog header="Car Detail" widgetVar="carDialog" resizable="false"
        id="carDlg" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" modal="true">

        <p:dataList id="display" value="#{tableBean.selectedCar}"
            var="selectedWorkSpaceItem"
            style="border: 0px solid gray;padding-bottom:1px;">
            <p:inputTextarea value="#{selectedWorkSpaceItem.color}">

            </p:inputTextarea>

        </p:dataList>

    </p:dialog>

</h:form>
```

My managed bean

```
public class TableBean implements Serializable {
    private final static String[] colors;

    private final static String[] manufacturers;

    static {
        colors = new String[10];
        colors[0] = "Black";
        colors[1] = "White";
        colors[2] = "Green";
        colors[3] = "Red";
        colors[4] = "Blue";
        colors[5] = "Orange";
        colors[6] = "Silver";
        colors[7] = "Yellow";
        colors[8] = "Brown";
        colors[9] = "Maroon";

        manufacturers = new String[10];
        manufacturers[0] = "Mercedes";
        manufacturers[1] = "BMW";
        manufacturers[2] = "Volvo";
        manufacturers[3] = "Audi";
        manufacturers[4] = "Renault";
        manufacturers[5] = "Opel";
        manufacturers[6] = "Volkswagen";
        manufacturers[7] = "Chrysler";
        manufacturers[8] = "Ferrari";
        manufacturers[9] = "Ford";
    }

    private List<Car> cars;

    private Car selectedCar;
    private CarDataModel mediumCarsModel;  
    private Car[] selectedCars;

    public TableBean() {
        cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

        populateRandomCars(cars, 50);
        mediumCarsModel = new CarDataModel(cars);
    }

    private void populateRandomCars(List<Car> list, int size) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
            list.add(new Car(getRandomModel(), getRandomYear(), getRandomManufacturer(), getRandomColor()));
    }

    public Car getSelectedCar() {
        return selectedCar;
    }

    public void setSelectedCar(Car selectedCar) {
        this.selectedCar = selectedCar;
    }

    public List<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    private int getRandomYear() {
        return (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1960);
    }

    private String getRandomColor() {
        return colors[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];
    }

    private String getRandomManufacturer() {
        return manufacturers[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];
    }

    private String getRandomModel() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8);
    }

    public CarDataModel getMediumCarsModel() {

        if(mediumCarsModel==null) {
            System.out.println("yes it is null!!!!!!");
            mediumCarsModel = new CarDataModel(cars);
        }

        return mediumCarsModel;
    }

    public void setMediumCarsModel(CarDataModel mediumCarsModel) {
        this.mediumCarsModel = mediumCarsModel;
    }

    public Car[] getSelectedCars() {
        return selectedCars;
    }

    public void setSelectedCars(Car[] selectedCars) {
        this.selectedCars = selectedCars;
    }

}
```

Is there any way using which i can display the content in dialog text area?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using @annotations to mark your beans? Or `faces-config.xml` file? Try to annotate your bean with `@ManagedBean` and `@ViewScoped`. Take a look [in this J2EE 6 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/girch.html) too.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TableBean implements Serializable {
    private final static String[] colors;

    private final static String[] manufacturers;

    static {
        colors = new String[10];
        colors[0] = "Black";
        colors[1] = "White";
        colors[2] = "Green";
        colors[3] = "Red";
        colors[4] = "Blue";
        colors[5] = "Orange";
        colors[6] = "Silver";
        colors[7] = "Yellow";
        colors[8] = "Brown";
        colors[9] = "Maroon";

        manufacturers = new String[10];
        manufacturers[0] = "Mercedes";
        manufacturers[1] = "BMW";
        manufacturers[2] = "Volvo";
        manufacturers[3] = "Audi";
        manufacturers[4] = "Renault";
        manufacturers[5] = "Opel";
        manufacturers[6] = "Volkswagen";
        manufacturers[7] = "Chrysler";
        manufacturers[8] = "Ferrari";
        manufacturers[9] = "Ford";
    }

    private List<Car> cars;

    private Car selectedCar;
    private CarDataModel mediumCarsModel;  
    private Car[] selectedCars;

    public TableBean() {
        cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

        populateRandomCars(cars, 50);
        mediumCarsModel = new CarDataModel(cars);
    }

    private void populateRandomCars(List<Car> list, int size) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
            list.add(new Car(getRandomModel(), getRandomYear(), getRandomManufacturer(), getRandomColor()));
    }

    public Car getSelectedCar() {
        return selectedCar;
    }

    public void setSelectedCar(Car selectedCar) {
        this.selectedCar = selectedCar;
    }

    public List<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    private int getRandomYear() {
        return (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1960);
    }

    private String getRandomColor() {
        return colors[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];
    }

    private String getRandomManufacturer() {
        return manufacturers[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];
    }

    private String getRandomModel() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8);
    }

    public CarDataModel getMediumCarsModel() {

        if(mediumCarsModel==null) {
            System.out.println("yes it is null!!!!!!");
            mediumCarsModel = new CarDataModel(cars);
        }

        return mediumCarsModel;
    }

    public void setMediumCarsModel(CarDataModel mediumCarsModel) {
        this.mediumCarsModel = mediumCarsModel;
    }

    public Car[] getSelectedCars() {
        return selectedCars;
    }

    public void setSelectedCars(Car[] selectedCars) {
        this.selectedCars = selectedCars;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes,i have annotated.It is viewscoped

Answer (score 0):

1.You need to add rowKey in your dataTable.

```
<p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" rowKey="#{car.model}" value="#{tableBean.mediumCarsModel}"
selection="#{tableBean.selectedCars}">
```

2.You need to have one button say in the header of the datatable which you'll click to display the dialog. Since your are selecting multiple rows, then you don't need a button on each row as shown in the example.

```
<f:facet name="header">
  <p:commandButton value="Click" onclick="PF('carDialog').show();" update=":form:display" />
</f:facet>
```

3.What data would you want to display in your dialog TextArea? The datatable has multiple columns i.e Model, Year, Manufacturer, Color. You might want to change the component from textArea to any component that displays a list e.g dataList or datatable in your dialog.